# Query records for current month using Spring data jpa

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jpql

How to Query records for current month using Spring data jpa ?

I don't want to use raw sql and dont want to send start date and end date as arguments.

If there is no option in Data jpa please let me know the JPQL

Answer (score 1):

If your ORM provider is Hibernate (default in Spring) you can use `year` and `month` [HQL functions](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-functions) in your query:

```
@Query("select e from MyEntity e where year(e.createdAt) = year(current_date) and  month(e.createdAt) = month(current_date)")
List<MyEntity> getAllOfCurrentMonth();
```